# I want to pass a parameter from jQuery.click() method

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onclick, this

```
<script type='text/javascript'>

            $(window).load(function() {
                $(document).ready(function() {
                    $('table tr').each(function() {
                        if ($(this).find('td').eq(6).text() === 'Start') {
                            $(this).css('background', 'yellow');
                            $(this).addClass('Start_Point');
                            $(this).click(a);
                        }
                    });
                });
            });

            function a()
            {
                alert();
            }

        </script>
```

I want send this object to my method using .click ..

I am already do following bt its not work . the method a() is calling when the function match case for 'start' which is wrong i want when user click on table the function a() will call

```
<script type='text/javascript'>

            $(window).load(function() {
                $(document).ready(function() {
                    $('table tr').each(function() {
                        if ($(this).find('td').eq(6).text() === 'Start') {
                            $(this).css('background', 'yellow');
                            $(this).addClass('Start_Point');
                            $(this).click(a(this));//This 
                        }
                    });
                });
            });

            function a()
            {
                alert();
            }

        </script>
```

Comment: To explain your problem, you are already invoking your function `a` in your click event handler. `a()` is executing/invoking the function and passing its result to the click handler, you should just do `$(this).click(a);`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass an anonymous callback function as the click handler which will call the method `a` with desired parameters

```
$(this).click(function(){
    a(this)
});
```

Comment: jQuery will bind `this` in the event callback to be the element, so just doing `$(this).click(a);` would also work, but wrapping it in an anonymous function makes it a bit clearer what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$(function(){
$(this).click(function(){
    a(this)
});
})
```

Answer (score 0):

then u can try

```
$('.Start_Point').click(function(){
    a(this)
});
```